# callback function doesn't worl js

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to create a callback function. Function getPosts i am using like a callback function in getResult. GetPost create array, which use getResult function. But when i call a function getResult is executed only getPosts function

```
function getPosts(index) {
  let arr = index.split(' ');
  console.log(arr);}

  function getResult (callback) {
    callback(index)
    let show = arr[0]+arr[2]+arr[1];
    console.log(show);
  }
```

Comment: You never call `getResult` within your code snippet at all.

Answer (score 0):

First you're trying to use `arr` which is a local array in another function and cannot be used elsewhere.
I believe you want to use the `getPosts()` function as an argument to the `getResult()` function:
Hope this code helps you:

```
function getPosts(index) {
  let arr = index.split(' ');
  console.log(arr);
  return arr;
  }

  function getResult (callback) {
    let show = callback[0]+callback[2]+callback[1];
    console.log(show);
  }

  getPosts('my data here');
  getResult(getPosts('my data here'));
```

Comment: Thanks, that what i want to do